# Create a rotation about the forward vector

Tags: vector, matrix, xna, rotation, xna-4.0

This is probably more of a Math subject area, but I'm hoping it's simple enough that some other dev out there might know.

Situation: I have an airplane game. I need to Pitch, Yaw, and Roll (Rotate about x,y,z) the plane with respect to the plane's orientation.

Problem: I can make the plane model rotate, however the rotations are global to the model. For example, when the plane is facing forward, applying a `CreateRotationZ()` works fine, but if the model is pointing upward (90 degree pitch), apply the `CreateRotationZ()` doesn't cause the plane to roll (with respect to the planes orientation), it causes it to yaw.

Comment: You know there is `CreateRotationX` and `CreateRotationY` as well? However, there will be a bit more complicated mathematics when the plane is at different angles. But it'll be a combination of the 3 methods.

Comment: Yes, CreateRotationZ(Yaw), CreateRotationX(Pitch), and CreateRotationY(Roll). These dont work though as they rotate without regard to the orientation on the plane as explained.

I have however come very close using:

Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Roll) * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), Pitch) * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0,1,0), Yaw);
Airframe.Orientation = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(rot);

If you roll the plane to the right, applying pitch correctly works, but yaw does not. Very Frustrating

Comment: Yes you'll need to axes local to your ship, not world axes. The rotation matrix of your ship will have accessors to get (Forward, Backward, Left, Right, Up, and Down), you can rotate around those vectors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a position (Vector3) and rotation (Matrix) on your Object/Entity/Ship, and then you can use the following code sample to move or rotate it in any of its local axes.

**For example, you want to roll an airplane 45 degrees (this is the rotation about the forward vector you were asking about):**

```
Entity plane = new Entity();
plane.Roll(MathHelper.PiOver4);
```

**Or pitch roll the airplane 90 degrees:**

```
plane.Pitch(MathHelper.PiOver2);
```

**And here's the code sample**

```
public class Entity
{
    Vector3 position = Vector3.Zero;
    Matrix rotation = Matrix.Identity;

    public void Yaw(float amount)
    {
        this.rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Up, amount);
    }

    public void YawAroundWorldUp(float amount)
    {
        this.rotation *= Matrix.CreateRotationY(amount);
    }

    public void Pitch(float amount)
    {
        this.rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Right, amount);
    }

    // This is the specific method you were asking for in the question title
    public void Roll(float amount)
    {
        this.rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Forward, amount);
    }

    public void Strafe(float amount)
    {
        this.position += this.rotation.Right * amount;
    }

    public void GoForward(float amount)
    {
        this.position += this.rotation.Forward * amount;
    }

    public void Jump(float amount)
    {
        this.position += this.rotation.Up * amount;
    }

    public void Rise(float amount)
    {
        this.position += Vector3.Up * amount;
    }
}
```

If you want a smooth movement you'll want to use these in very small increments, and use elapsed time in your calculations for the `amount` that you use.

Comment: +1 This is good advice. The only comment I have to it that whenever you use CreateFromAxisAngle, the axis (in your Pitch() method, the this.rotation.Right) should be normalized just before using it. If you let that slide, the floating point error will compound (not accumulate, but compound) and your matrix will distort relatively quickly. If you normalize the axis, however, the error will merely accumulate and would take hours or days to noticeably distort which is usually acceptable.

Comment: The vectors that XNA gives you when you access a Matrix class are always normalized I believe, so long as you don't manually screw with the Matrix itself (alter its values manually rather than using the provided functions). But you bring up a good point, I think I'll write a unit-test that rotates a Matrix about different axes, and after each rotation checks against known values, this should let me see if it's drifting or distorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Matrix.CreateWorld(), is better for what you want, 
the parameters are the position, the forward vector and the up vector.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975261.aspx

Comment: How would you go about implementing it,
On a side note, i just found the answer, as apparently many developers face until they see the light.
Keeping track of global rotations is BAD. Simply updating the orientation by slight amounts every update is GOOD. Full solution to come tomorrow when my 8 hour wait for posting my own answer on my question is up, lol.